# Access Crosstab Multiple Rows as column headers?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to mimic the spreadsheet layout (picture 1) in MS Access using a Crosstab query. It's quite trivial to set up multiple row headers with the query builder, but I can't seem to find a way to have that same information just with the X and Y axis swapped.

I'm a novice in SQL, so I might be able to figure some new query techniques out if I'm pointed in the right direction.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Access CROSSTAB cannot do that. I think the old PivotTable tool could. Access crosstab would have to concatenated fields for a single column header. The number of stores would be a separate query calculation.

Comment: nice job setting up the question except you didn't include the two key steps.  The data you have and the query results (simplified please) you want.  For instance the access tables have no element ID while the excel table does.

Comment: Respectfully, mazoula, I think you just didn't understand my question. The Access crosstab screenshot has the element IDs across the top. The three row headers, "Prekit", "Vendor" and "No of Stores" are all static, non aggregated data points.

I should note, Element ID in the spreadsheet is ITEM_NO in access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do this unless you know how many Prekits you have in your data.  My official answer is that often when you build a database you want to show any stake holders the database can reproduce their paperwork.  However while access can do cross-tab queries the access reporting functions don't work well with cross-tab queries.  Your cross-tab does contain all the information so I suggest you look up the export capabilities of Access.  Access can recreate the original Excel file  and insert the data into that file though you might have to write a little VBA code for the fine details.
Now to answer your actual question the Excel file has clear header and data sections and we have all the data in the cross-tab the problem is formatting which is the job of Access Reports.  However Access Reporting is opinionated.  Access reports are expected to be bound at design time which makes binding to a cross-tab query difficult.  Here is a link to a more detailed explanation and a work around for one type of data.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/05/23/using-crosstab-queries-in-reports/
However for my sample data I know the number of columns so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Query1 groups the data so the header section of the report has the right numbers to grab.  Query2 finishes the cross-tab.  The text boxes in the header section of the report are bound to Query1 with the dlookup function.
[image]

[image]

Query2 starts with query1:

[image]

[image]

query 2 is the datasource of the report and we lookup the header values from query1.  Below is the report:

[image]

```
'control source for kitting vendor textbox 1:
=DLookUp("VENDOR_NAME","Query1","ROW_ID = 1")

'control source for # of stores textbox 7:
=DLookUp("NO_OF_STORES","Query1","ROW_ID = 7")
```

Again, you can't make this report unless you know how many columns result from the cross-tab.  every time someone makes a new kit the report needs to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for putting so much time into composing this answer, Mazoula. This is extremely helpful!